# Can anyone recognize this window manufacturer?

Tags: windows

Can you identify this window manufacturer? I live in the Southeast.

[image]

Comment: Tempered glass and frame manufacturing is probably two different things.  The mark you show identifies the glass tempering foundry, not necessarily the manufacturer of the completed window. Are you seeking glass replacement or frame parts?

Comment: Related: https://oakpointpartners.com/transaction/arch-aluminum-glass-co-inc-remnant-assets/

Comment: The southeast of what?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean, ouch!!!

Comment: @jsotola yeah, op’s best bet is to look for markings on the frame like Tyson suggested and hope it wasn’t made by them

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean, it looks like Arch were a window manufacturer ..... they were not a glass manufacturer

Comment: @jsotola hopefully they did both